# Prove for all $a, b, c \in \mathbb {R^+}$ ${a\over\sqrt{a+b}} + {b\over\sqrt{b+c}} + {c\over\sqrt{c+a}} \gt \sqrt{a+b+c}$ is true

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove for all $a, b, c \in \mathbb {R^+}$ $${a\over\sqrt{a+b}} + {b\over\sqrt{b+c}} + {c\over\sqrt{c+a}} \gt \sqrt{a+b+c}$$ is true

I have been studying about inequalities and how to prove different inequalities, and I stumbled over this question which I failed to answer. I failed to see a connection between $\sqrt{a+b+c} \text{ and} {a\over\sqrt{a+b}} + {b\over\sqrt{b+c}} + {c\over\sqrt{c+a}}$. Is there any way I can prove this question and if there is can you please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need only [Jensen](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf) applied to convex function $f(x)={1 \over \sqrt{x}}$:

$$LHS=a\space f(a+b)+b\space f(b+c)+c\space f(c+a)\ge(a+b+c)\space f(\frac{a(a+b)+b(b+c)+c(c+a)}{a+b+c})$$

$$LHS\ge(a+b+c)\space f(\frac{(a+b+c)^2-ab-bc-ac}{a+b+c})$$

$$LHS\ge(a+b+c)\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{(a+b+c)^2-ab-bc-ac}}$$

$$LHS\gt(a+b+c)\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{(a+b+c)^2}}$$

$$LHS\gt\sqrt{a+b+c}$$

Answer (score 1):

You may proceed as follows using convexity of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$:

- $\sum_{k=1}^3 \lambda_k f(x_k) \geq f\left( \sum_{k=1}^3 \lambda_k x_k\right)$ with $\sum_{k=1}^3 \lambda_k = 1$, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3 \geq 0$
  $$
  \begin{eqnarray*} {a\over\sqrt{a+b}} + {b\over\sqrt{b+c}} + {c\over\sqrt{c+a}}
  & = & (a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(a+b+c)(a+b)} \\
  & \stackrel{Jensen}{\geq} & (a+b+c)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a+b+c}\sum_{cyc}a(a+b)}} \\
  & \color{blue}{>} & (a+b+c)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a+b+c}\sum_{cyc}a(a+b\color{blue}{+c})}} \\
  & = & (a+b+c)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a+b+c}(a+b+c)^2}} \\ 
  & = & \color{blue}{\sqrt{a+b+c}}
  \end{eqnarray*}
  $$

Answer (score 0):

> **Holder's Inequality:** Let $a_{ij}, 1 \leq i \leq m , 1 \leq j \leq m $ be positive real numbers. Then the following inequality holds:
>
> $$\prod_{i = 1}^{m}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_{ij}\right) \geq
> \left(\sum_{j = 1}^{n} \sqrt[m]{\prod_{i = 1}^{m} a_{ij}}\right)^{m}.
> > $$
>
> For example, consider real numbers $a, b, c, p, q, r, x, y, z$. Then,
>
> $$(a^{3} + b^{3} + c^{3})(p^{3} + q^{3} + r^{3})(x^{3} + y^{3} +
> > z^{3}) \geq (aqx + bqy + crz)^{3}. $$

We have

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + b}} >  \sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + 2b}}. $$

By Holder's Inequality,

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + 2b}}\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + 2b}}\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} a(a + 2b)\right) \geq (a + b+ c)^{3}. $$

Thus,

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a + 2b}}\right)^{2} \geq a + b + c, $$

and the result follows.

Comment: How did you use Holder's Inequality to get that?

Comment: Check my example in the edited post @Tralala

Comment: There's a typo. $\sum_{cyc} a(a+b)$ should be $\sum_{cyc} a(a+2b) [= (a+b+c)^2]$.

Comment: Fixed it. @Song

Answer (score 0):

too long; can't fit into a comment. I think @Ekesh 's answer has a little flaw: @Ekesh please see if mine is correct.

---

Your inequality is equivalent to

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + b}}\geq a+b+c$$

By Holder's,

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + b}}\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a + b}}\right)\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} a(a + b)\right) \geq (a + b+ c)^{3}.$$

We notice that (by expanding),

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}} a(a + b)\right) \leq (a + b+ c)^{2}.$$

It is valid to divide the above equation with this as $\fbox{1}$ It is positive $\fbox{2}$ This move removes more value at the RHS, which will not affect the sign.

Hence we get

$$\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a + b}}\right)^{2} \geq a + b + c,$$

which is what we want.

Comment: @Ekesh please read my answer

Comment: yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Why downvote? :(

Comment: @Tralala I don't understand that downvote either so I'm fixing that with my upvote :)